# bind_param on a non-object error on mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I got an error of :

> Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

in below code, I have no idea what's wrong, everything seem just fine for me.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO list(title, 
topicDesc,date,kod,country) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssis', 'yo','yo desc','1 may 2015,','123','US');
```

Comment: Your `prepare` failed for some reason (and therefore returned `false`), check the error logs.

Comment: @CD001 where to check? I `echo` $db->error it give me nothing?

Comment: Check your DB connection and make sure you're not mixing MySQL APIs, such as PDO. If I had a nickel for everytime I've seen that happen, I'd have 10 bucks worth. Remember to execute your query. Use `if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$db->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` to catch the error.

Comment: so, where are we at with this question? comment above make any sense?

Comment: you posted this already http://stackoverflow.com/q/29800468/

Answer (score 0):

$db is not set to an instance of the mysqli class object.  This most commonly happens when there is failure in the connection statement. See the [mysqli manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) for proper syntax and help debugging errors

Comment: This should probably be a comment not an answer.

Comment: I'd say it was as good an answer as the question could be given.  I'll change to comment if you feel it does not answer the actual question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

Try This one It's Working

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO list (title, topicDesc, date,kod,country) 
    VALUES (:title1, :topicDesc1, :date1, :kod1,:country1)");

$stmt->execute(array(
    ':title1' => 'col2',
    ':topicDesc1' => 'col3',
    ':date1' => 'col4', 
    ':kod1' => 'col4', 
    ':country1' => 'col4'));
```